# Material Mui . Remove padding from grid item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to remove padding 8px that is added to grid item . Below is my code. It is not working at all . It has .Mui-GridItem : padding 8px . I am not able to remove it. Please help

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YtxE.png)

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { AddressComponent } from "./addressDetails";
import { BasicComponent } from "./basicDetails";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

//interface DetailsFormProps {}

const opco = "stc";
const handleSubmit = (values:any) => {
  console.log(values);
};

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  boolspac: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0)   
  },
}))


export default function DetailsForm() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container  direction="column" alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
      <Grid container  className={classes.boolspac} item xs={6} >
        <BasicComponent  opco={opco} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid container item xs={6}>
        <AddressComponent onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
   </div>
    
  );
}
```

Comment: remove the ```spacing={1}```

Answer (score 0):

I think why you meet this problem is because you using the wrong import by makeStyle, you can try to change the import like this:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
```